# JQuery Animate Jumpy Only in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-animate, css-float

I'm working on a page where I'd like to have a hiding left navigation bar. I'm running into the problem only with Safari, there are no issues in Chrome, FF, Opera, IE7+.

When the sliding animation is about to complete in Safari you'll see some content briefly jump to its original position then disappear. I have been researching for a while without much luck. It seems like most of the time it's padding or margin, but they are set to zero and I've tried two CSS resets. It seems to me like it's something to do with the floats. I tried playing with Clear but no luck.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eLvBr/6/)

And the relevant animation:

```
$('#btnHide').click(function() {
    $("#divNavContent").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000, function() {
        $("#divNavHidden").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 500);
    });

});

$('#btnShowMenu').click(function() {
    $("#divNavHidden").animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 500, function() {
        $("#divNavContent").animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: try changing the easing property of the animation to `'linear'`

Comment: It looks like the width is only set during the animation, then the display is set to none and the width property is removed so the original css takes over, maybe using static numbers rather than "toggle" would work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the `float: left;` on `#divLeft` But you can remove the float from `#divLeft` and maintain your same structure.

Also add `margin-left: 4px;` to `#content` because the two divs get a bit squished when you remove the float.

Seems like its more of a bug in Safari and not your fault.